# Connect Nginx Load Balancer with Memcache server

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, memcached

I m using Nginx as Load balancer with ngx_http_memcached_module and I installed a Memcached Server that I would like to connect it with Nginx to make it obtain responses from a Memcached server.

Load balancer.conf (Nginx)

```
upstream backend  {
#  least_conn;
  server 192.168.222.130 weight=1 max_fails=3  fail_timeout=30s;
  server 192.168.222.131 weight=2 max_fails=3  fail_timeout=30s;
}
        proxy_buffer_size 1k;
        proxy_buffers 24 4k;


        proxy_cache_path /var/lib/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=backcache:8m max_size=50m;
        proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$is_args$args";
        proxy_cache_valid 200 302 10m;
        proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;


server {
 listen 80;


 location / {
   proxy_cache backcache;
   proxy_cache_bypass $http_cache_control;
   add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
   proxy_pass  http://backend;
 }


location /wp-admin {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.222.130/wp-login.php;
}
}
```

Memcached Conf:

```
PORT="11211"
USER="memcached"
MAXCONN="1024"
CACHESIZE="64"
OPTIONS="192.168.222.139"
```

Nginx Example Configuration from the [official website](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_memcached_module.html)

But I don't understand what each ligne is doing and can't apply it to my server.

```
server {
    location / {
        set            $memcached_key "$uri?$args";
        memcached_pass host:11211;
        error_page     404 502 504 = @fallback;
    }

    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass     http://backend;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the specific question/issue you're encountering?

Comment: I still didn't encounter any issue since i still don't know how to connect Nginx with Memcache i need someone to show me how ?

Comment: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_memcached_module.html

Comment: yes i saw this configuration but didn't understand it and don't know how to apply it to my server

Comment: I suggest you need to hire a professional, or try it yourself and post any specific problems you find.